# How to insert multiple datatable data into one datatable c#

Tags: c#, datatable, addition

I have a function which will return multiple ItemIDs as

```
           for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                ItemID = int.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["item_Id"].ToString());
                dtAtlr = prodctsDCCls.getItemIds(ItemID);
                //dtItems = dtAtlr.Copy();
            }
```

I want to keep on searching for all ItemIds from the same table and have to save all the data in one datatable.If I copy one datatable to another datatable, that is replacing the previous datatable. but I need all the data. Please anybody help me

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you have tried, what was the problem(was there an exception?) or what's the desired result. Provide a short(but complete) sample, you can replace your `getItemIds` with a  foo-method that returns a `DataTable`.

Comment: Side-note: If `item_Id` is already an `int` use the strongly typed `DataRow` extension method [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx)(which also supports nullable types):  `item_Id = dt.Rows[i].Field<int>("item_Id");`

Comment: that is replacing the previous datatable. this is my problem sir

Comment: Iam doing dtItems=dtAtlr.Copy(); so dat it is replacing the previous data with the new data.. :)

Comment: Thanks you sir.. I tried dt.Clone and tried to copytodatatable method too with a foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) to merge two data tables. So your code would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ItemID = int.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["item_Id"].ToString());
    dtAtlr.Merge(prodctsDCCls.getItemIds(ItemID)); // For Merging
}
```

By using `DataTable.Copy`, your datatable `dtAtlr` will have the last returned `DataTable` against the `ItemID`

Answer (score 1):

You can check  [**DataTable.Merge**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx)

> Merge the specified DataTable with the current DataTable.